# Why am I unable to start my Genymotion emulator for Samsung Galaxy S4?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation, genymotion

I'm new to Android Studio and have been setting up Genymotion to emulate the Hello World app given for Android Studio.

I installed Genymotion as a plugin within Android Studio, and I have configured both Android Studio and Genymotion for my Samsung Galaxy S4, however, when I activate Genymotion Device Manager in Android Studio and select my device the Start button is simply grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your emulator from Genymotion app is off (or not running)? I was having the same problem and I realized that I tried to start the emulator from Android Studio with the emulator from Genymotion already running at the same time. You need to close one or the other to run from another application.